# Integrating Silverlight into aspx page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

How we can add the silverlight project into a aspx page. I had created one digital clock project in silverlight. But i don't know how to integrate with the aspx page. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by integrate it with an aspx page. Do want to add the silverlight control or object to a web page, or is there a deeper integration that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to add the silverlight control or object to a web page..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear: There is no need to use .Net to host silverlight.

It is a browser plugin and you use the html object tag to host it. Here is all the information you need:

**[How to: Add Silverlight to a Web Page by Using HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx)**

Also, here is a quick example:

```
<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
</object>
```

If you are using Asp.Net, There is a project that contains sample server controls for hosting silverlight objects. You can get it here: [ASP.NET Server Controls for Silverlight Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetprojects/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2957)